# Create ODataModel entries which depend on others

Tags: odata, sapui5

Here is the problem I'm facing:
I have an OData service which provides the entities Category and Product with a 1:n relationship.
From a SAPUI5-App I want to create a new Entity for both the Category and the Product at the same time. I do this with the createEntry-Method of [ODataModel (v2)](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.html). After using the createEntry-Method for both of my EntitySets I have a local [Context](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Context.html) object for each of them inside my ODataModel. However these two objects are still unrelated to each other.
How can I tell the Product object that it belongs to the Category object, so that they have a relationship when I submit them to the OData service with the submitChanges-Method of the ODataModel?

Edit: The generation of the primary keys is on the server-side. So the context objects I receive from the createEntry-Method of the ODataModel do not have a Primary Key yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a deep insert. Let's take an example of Sales order. You have a Sales Order Header and Sales Order Line Items which should be created in the backend at the same time in a single transaction. So in the data model there needs to be an association between SO Header and SO Item and the backend logic needs to implement CREATE_DEEP_ENTITY method. To create it from SAPUI5 you need something like this:

```
var itemData = this.getModel("itemModel").getData(); //Array of items
var newSo = {
"ID": 1,                   //Header data
"Description": "test",     //Header data
"Items": itemData.itemSet  //Array of items
}

var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
oModel.create('/SalesOrderSet', newSO);
```

Comment: Yes this looks promising. I will try to get this to work tomorrow. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

Very good question! In fact, OData offers something called "Content ID". SAP Gateway even supports this, for details have a look at [this beautiful blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/02/15/introduction-odata-batch-processing-with-content-id-in-sap-gateway/).

Unfortunately, SAPUI5 does not support this currently out of the box as far as I know. There is even a [feature request on github](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/978) for this which I have also linked on the blog.

Comment: That's an awesome feature. I would love to use this. Hopefully it will be integrated in SAPUI5 soon. Thanks for linking the blog